# Solving very intermittent exception in .net app

Tags: .net, debugging, exception

I have an asp.net MVC app in production that very seldom but very consistently is throwing the same exception and I don't know why. I cannot, no matter what I do, reproduce the exception in neither the production nor development environments.

I am logging all unhandled exceptions. I have the date/time, controller, action, exception message, and call stack of each logged exception. So, I have a good idea where this is happening. Just not why.

To solve, I am considering wrapping this code in a try/catch and manually logging the names/values of all relevant variables. I would deploy this new logging capability and once solved, I would remove it.

But, then I was thinking how I bet there is a better, more portable way of doing this. Can anyone help?

#### EDIT

[This is what I am currently working off of.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1563210/exlogging.html)

Comment: Post the code and the exception?

Comment: @Paddy - The details of the exception aren't really important. I am more interested in how to solve problems in general.

Comment: OK, but from the sound of it, if you're already logging the error, then there's not too much else you can do with out a recreation.  I'd second the ELMAH recommendation below for the amount of detail you get.

Comment: OK, so it's the model that is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/)?

> ELMAH (Error Logging Modules and
>   Handlers) is an application-wide error
>   logging facility that is completely
>   pluggable. It can be dynamically added
>   to a running ASP.NET web application,
>   or even all ASP.NET web applications
>   on a machine, without any need for
>   re-compilation or re-deployment.
>
> Once ELMAH has been dropped into a
>   running web application and configured
>   appropriately, you get the following
>   facilities without changing a single
>   line of your code:
>
> - Logging of nearly all unhandled exceptions.
> - A web page to remotely view the entire log of recoded exceptions.
> - A web page to remotely view the full details of any one logged
>     exception.
> - In many cases, you can review the original yellow screen of death
>     that ASP.NET generated for a given
>     exception, even with customErrors mode
>     turned off.
> - An e-mail notification of each error at the time it occurs.
> - An RSS feed of the last 15 errors from the log.

ELMAH won't log the state of the application, but perhaps you could throw a custom exception that would encapsulate any state you need to see.  Are you looking to log something like a core dump?  Perhaps something like [debugdiag](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=28BD5941-C458-46F1-B24D-F60151D875A3&displaylang=en) would be better:

> The Debug Diagnostic Tool (DebugDiag) is designed to assist in troubleshooting issues such as hangs, slow performance, memory leaks or fragmentation, and crashes in any user-mode process. The tool includes additional debugging scripts focused on Internet Information Services (IIS) applications, web data access components, COM+ and related Microsoft technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Are you catching a database exception somewhere and somehow your model variable doesn't get filled, or your code doesn't branch off to indicate the need to try again (i.e. error page/message)?

I also would recommend [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/), it gives you a lot of the HTTP/REQUEST/RESPONSE type headers from the request and it may have enough information for you to debug the issue better/faster.  You'll probably have to do some work to get Elmah working because you already have a catch-all handler/logging mechanism, so there are not really any uncaught exceptions that ELMAH could handle just out of the box.